Silverstripe TableView template override
Does anyone know if there is an option to override the TableView template in the Silverstripe asset-admin.
I am wanting to view image filenames as well as to be able to sort them, but it seems like there is no way to modify this component directly.
I have tried to modify this component using the default injector but have not been able to.
